# Chef hangs with bundle install

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, bundle, chef-infra

when I deploy with chef to an EC2 box it works fine at the first deploy, but every subsequent deploy hangs here

```
* execute[bundle install --deployment] action run
```

the relevant chef code is

```
execute "bundle install --deployment" do
   cwd "#{app_path}/current"
end
```

At this point all the gems are obviously installed (due to the fact that the 1st deploy succeeds).

the command chef runs is

```
 /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/chef/embedded/bin/bundle install --deployment
```

Which runs fine when I execute it directly on the box:

```
Your bundle is complete!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in fact now the first deploy hangs as well. executing the above command has the same result (Your bundle is complete!). Now I think that the bundle install takes ages and the deploy command times out?

Comment: I added --verbose after --deployment for the bundle install call, now it runs fine on two ec2 machines both at deployment and re-deployment. that might not have been the solution though..

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. Could you please answer your own question and mark the answer as correct?